# onClick, How to know checkbox is selected or unselected in multiple checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I found many checkbox related questions but not was related like mine. Please check and help.

I have 10+ checkboxs which are dynamically creating as per the API data (looping list).

Here I want to know onClick whether the checkbox is unchecked or checked (accordingly i'll call different API).

To know/tack the checked or unchecked, i tried using the state. But the problem is while i'm checking/ unchecking all checkboxs are affecting with same.

Please help me handle that individually.

My code as follows:

```
 this.state = {
        isChecked: true,
    };

 handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log("clicked", e.fieldId);
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      isChecked: !prevState.isChecked,
    }));

 if(this.state.isChecked){
       // update to API 1
  }else{
     // update to API 2
  }
  };

 <input
         type="checkbox"
         checked={this.state.isChecked}
         onClick={() => this.handleClick(subitems)}
         name="check"
 />
 <label className="form-check-label cost-blue">
 {subitems.message}
 </label>
```

Note: some checkboxs are already checked as per API list data. But by using the state, i unable to handle that also

Edit: This how i'm looping from API

```
Object.keys(dataMap).map((value, key) => {
                return (
                  <div className="mt-10">
                    <div className="row text-center m-0 p-box white">
                      <div>
                        <img src={plant_icon} alt="plant" />
                        <span className="mb-0">&nbsp;&nbsp; {value}</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    {dataMap[value].map((subitems) => {
                      return (
                        <div className="form-check custom-cb m-10">
                          <input
                            className="form-check-input mt-7"
                            type="checkbox"
                            checked={this.state.isChecked}
                            onClick={() => this.handleClick(subitems)}
                            name="check"
                          />
                          <label className="form-check-label cost-blue">
                            {subitems.message}
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      );
                    })}
                  </div>
                );
              })
```

Comment: Could you add more details about how you are calling this component? It seems from your comments like all of your checkboxes are accidentally sharing the same state, which shouldn't happen if your components are well isolated. It would be useful to see where you're mapping over the list coming back from the API and rendering the checkbox components 